# HTML menu markup position

Tags: html, css, responsive

I cannot understand how, in my case, possible to properly positioned the menu by creating only one class menu, instead of menu_left and menu_right classes.
How can I optimize css here?

Here's code example:
html:

```
            <div class="menu_left" >
                <div class="menu__item">
                    <a href="#" title="Shop" class="menu__item__link"><span class="menu__item__link__text">SHOP</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__item">
                    <a href="" title="about" class="menu__item__link"><span class="menu__item__link__text">ABOUT</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
                <a href=""  class="logo">
                    <img src="assets/sds.jpgf" class="logo__image">
                </a>
                    <div class ="menu_right">
                <div class="menu__item">
                    <a href="" title="cart" class="menu__item__link"><span class="menu__item__link__text">CART</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__item">
                    <a href="" title="eur" class="menu__item__link "><span class="menu__item__link__text">EUR</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[Menu Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsJsU.png)
css

```
.menu_left {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
      position: relative;
      top: auto;
      right: auto;
      bottom: auto;
      left: auto;
      background: transparent;
      float: left;
      width: auto;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transition: none;
      -moz-transition: none;
      transition: none; }
      .menu_right{
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
        right: auto;
        bottom: auto;
        left: auto;
        background: transparent;
        float: right;
        width: auto;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: none;
        -moz-transition: none;
        transition: none; }
    }
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example (in this case the CSS). Next to that: your HTML is invalid, only a `li` element can be a direct descendant of a `ul`.

Comment: @Roy Okay, updated.

Comment: You appear to have two menus (and I would have expected each to be constructed as lists not nested divs), one each side of a logo. Could you describe a bit more why you feel they should be one and what you mean by 'optimise the CSS' - perhaps optimising accessibility, e.g. considering what screen readers will make of the structure, is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try it with Flexbox

[See flexbox menu here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmZiJ.png)

### HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="img"> <!-- replace div with the <img src="" alt="" /> tag -->
        img here
    </div>
    <ul>
     <li>
         <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height:  30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color:  #fff;
}
```

Comment: tip : you can add the css language identifier to highlight the codes

Answer (score 0):

To optimize CSS when using very similar settings, use three classes instead of two: One common class for both elements which contains all the common settings, and two separate classes for the two elements which contain the different settings:

CSS:

```
.menu_all {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  background: transparent;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  transition: none; 
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  background: transparent;
}

.menu_left {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  float: left;
}
.menu_right{
  float: right;
}
```

and HTML:

```
 <div class="menu_all menu_left" >
      <div class="menu__item">
         <a href="#" title="Shop" class="menu__item__link"><span class="menu__item__link__text">SHOP</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu__item">
         <a href="" title="about" class="menu__item__link"><span class="menu__item__link__text">ABOUT</span></a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <a href=""  class="logo">
      <img src="assets/sds.jpgf" class="logo__image">
  </a>
  <div class ="menu_all menu_right">
      <div class="menu__item">
         <a href="" title="cart" class="menu__item__link"><span class="menu__item__link__text">CART</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu__item">
         <a href="" title="eur" class="menu__item__link "><span class="menu__item__link__text">EUR</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
```